# Better way to compute elliptic curves over finite fields?

Tags: elliptic-curves, isogenies

I've been using modular polynomials to compute isogeny vulcanoes with prime degree $l$ over finite fields $\mathbb{F}_p$, excluding cases containing the $j$-invariants $0$ and $1728$ or $j$-invariants with double roots on the polynomial, building the graph by at each step using the polynomial to find the neighbors of a vertex. This seemed like the obvious thing to do, and I have not previously questioned myself in this regard. But, now that I think about it, I have not seen any paper explicitly talking about doing this, I just assumed it was like that, but maybe there is a better way to compute the isogeny volcano graph than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper [Isogeny volcanoes by Andrew V. Sutherland](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5370) contains various improvements for computing isogeny volcanoes. The published version is in  *ANTS X—Proceedings of the Tenth Algorithmic Number Theory Symposium*, 507–530,
Open Book Ser., 1, Math. Sci. Publ., Berkeley, CA, 2013.

Comment: I've skimmed the paper you linked, and in an algorithm to find a path to the floor of a volcano he does use finding the roots of the polynomial $\Phi_l(j,X)$ to get the neighbors of a vertex. He does not give an algorithm to construct a full volcano, but if he builds paths on the graph like this, then his approach might be similar.